# Randomly getting an 404 no method error when calling the question endpoint

Tags: support, bug, questions

When calling the question endpoint for a given number of communities, I have been randomly getting the following error:

`{"error_id":404,"error_message":"no method found with this name","error_name":"no_method"}`

It seems to work 95% of the time, but we will randomly get these errors. It appears that we're calling the method correctly.

Here is an example of a url that failed:
`Url Called: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?fromdate=1695513600&todate=1695600000&order=desc&sort=activity&site=apple.stackexchange.com&filter=!*MZqiH2P51ejJkDY&page=1&key={stackapps_api_key}`

Anyone have any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Comment: Based on "[Some API requests to /users are failing with status code 404 errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426667/3773011)", try seeing if you still get the error when you don't ask for the `collectives` field.